# play_and_get_digits no input vs wrong input in Freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch

I am trying to implement the play_and_get_digits using ESL in nodejs.

The code is quite simple:

```
 conn.execute('play_and_get_digits', ${minValue} ${maxValue} ${tries} ${timeout} ${terminator} ${soundFile} ${invalidFile} ${var_name} ${regex} ${digit_timeout}`);
```

It works well. My only problem is when the caller does not enter anything. By default, it plays the audio defined in **invalidFile** which I use to inform the caller the value they entered is not valid. I would like to be able to differentiate between wrong input (e.g. digit 5 when only 1 or 2 are allowed) and no input at all.

What would the best way to do this be?

Thanks!